# Updating programs on hiren boot disk

Tags: boot, updates, hiren

Im trying to update ccleaner and other programs that come bundled with hiren boot disk, how easy is it and how is it done?

Comment: Looks like a lot of stuff on there is out of date, you might need to create your own 'Iaindude Book Disk'

Answer (score 0):

Hiren's BootCD is discontinued and has not been updated since 2012.

You should instead use
[Hiren’s BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/)
(Preinstallation Environment),
which is a restored edition of Hiren’s BootCD based on Windows 10 PE x64
and maintained by volunteers. It is described as :

> It includes the least, best and updated free tools used in Hiren’s BootCD. It is being developed for the new age computers, it supports UEFI booting and requires minimum 2 GB RAM.
>
> With the useful tools inside of the ISO, you can solve many problems related with your computer. It does not contain any pirated software, it includes only free and legal software.

You can see the list of included packages in the
[ISO Content page](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/),
where you can also download the latest version.

If you would like to help in keeping this boot CD up to date,
you may [contact](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/contact/)
the other volunteers, which should be the easiest route to take.

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE WAY TO USE ANY PORTABLE APPS IN HBCD PE X64.

1. I simply installed the HBCD PE x64 in pendrive.
2. Created a new folder in HBCD PE x64 drive & named it My Apps.
3. I copied all the new portable apps folder in it.
4. Open the app folder you want to use & simply run the EXE file.
5. Hola!!! you got it, you can run any portable programme like this in HBCD PE x64,

Comment: I don't see how you can copy files in to a folder My Apps